# Permission denied in character device

Tags: c, terminal, kernel, debian, linux-device-driver

I'm programming a device's driver module for the debian 6 kernel which acts as a FIFO device, the compilation is aparently correct, i use the following code to create it:

```
Major = register_chrdev(0, DEVICE_NAME, &fops); //Major is an integer value
if (Major < 0) {
  printk(KERN_ALERT "Registering char device failed with %d\n", Major);
  return -Major;
}
/*
 * Creation of buffer;
 */
if( (buf = create_cbuffer_t(MAX_BUFFER_SIZE)) == NULL){
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Error when creating the FIFO device.");
    return -EINVAL;
}
    printk(KERN_INFO "Buffer created without error.\n");
```

The major number asigned is 251, and i create it's file using this:

```
sudo mknod /dev/fifodev c 251 0
```

It works properly but when i try to access in terminal this is the result

```
dsouser@debian:~/Escritorio/Prac3/ParteB$ echo whatever > /dev/fifodev 
bash: /dev/fifodev: Permiso denegado **This means:Permission denied**
```

And this happens too:

```
dsouser@debian:~/Escritorio/Prac3/ParteB$ cat /dev/fifodev
cat: /dev/fifodev: Argumento inválido
```

What would be the problem within it or the right way to make it run?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

change the permission of `/dev/fifodev`

```
 sudo chmod 666 /dev/fifodev
```